# How to make Python classes for independent metrics and dependent metrics?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, series

I have some metrics which need to be turned into classes.

- Each metric has a `name` (string), a `unit` (string), and a `value` (series of values)
- Some metrics are dependent and calculated based on other metrics and need to also have the names of those metrics for later reference.

So in the code we have something like this:

```
# normal metrics 
metric_1 = series_1
metric_2 = series_2
metric_3 = series_3

# calculated metrics
# each needs to know the names of other metrics it uses to calculate 
metric_4 = metric_1 + metric_2
metric_5 = metric_2 - metric_3 * 100
metric_6 = metric_1 + metric_2 + metric_3
```

I try to have a class `Metric()` for indepedent metrics and a subclass `CalMetric()` for those dependent metrics. But the problem is `metric_4, metric_5, metric_6`, ... and more are all calculated differently. How can I structure this code into classes?

Comment: Are `metric_1, metric_2, ...` etc. the fields of the `Metric()` class or instances of the class?

Comment: @LockeDonohoe They should be instances of the class. The example code is not written in classes.

Answer (score 1):

Each composite metric could be in its own subclass, with a `compute` method particular to each subclass:

```
class Metric4(Metric):

    def __init__(self, metric_1, metric2):
        self.metric_1 = metric_1
        self.metric_2 = metric_2

    def compute(self):
        return self.metric_1 + self.metric_2
```